# Get virtual network details from Virtual Network gateway in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-network

How can I get virtual network name from Virtual network gateway in Azure. It is not listed as a property.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get virtual network name from Virtual network gateway in Azure. It is not listed as a property.

To get **virtual network name** from `Virtual network gateway`.

Here is the **PowerShell** command.

```
    $resourceGroupName = "<RG-NAMe>"
    $gatewayName = "<Gateway-Name>"
    $gateway = Get-AzVirtualNetworkGateway -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $gatewayName
    foreach ($ipConfig in $gateway.IpConfigurations) {
        $virtualNetworkName = ($ipConfig.Subnet.Id -split '/')[-3]
        Write-Output "Virtual Network Name: $virtualNetworkName"
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Reference:  [Get-AzVirtualNetworkGateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-azvirtualnetworkgateway?view=azps-10.2.0)